# Finding CDF of Composition of random variable and real function

Tags: probability, solution-verification, cumulative-distribution-functions

> **The Problem:** Suppose that $X$ is absolutely continuous with a PDF
>   $$f_X(t)=\begin{cases}e^{-t}&\text{if }t\geq0\\0&\text{if }t<0.\end{cases}$$
>   Let
>   $$g(x)=\begin{cases}x&\text{if }x\leq5\\6&\text{if }x>5.\end{cases}$$
>   Find the CDF of $Y=g(X)$. Check whether this is an absolutely continuous random variable and find its PDF if it has one.

**My Thoughts:** First we find the CDF of $X$ for later use. We have
$$F_X(t)=\int_{-\infty}^tf_X(s)\,ds=\begin{cases}0&\text{if }t<0\\1-e^{-t}&\text{if }t\geq0.\end{cases}$$
Therefore, $P(X\leq0)=0$. Next, if $0<t<6$ then $g(X)\leq t$ if and only if $X\leq t$ so that
$$P(g(X)\leq t)=P(X\leq t)=1-e^{-t}.$$
It follows that
$$F_Y(t)=\begin{cases}0&\text{if }t\leq0\\1-e^{-t}&\text{if }0<t<6\\1&\text{if }t\geq6.\end{cases}$$
Note that $F_Y$ is not continuous at $t=6$ and hence $Y$ is not absolutely continuous. Moreover, $Y$ cannot have a PDF since $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{d}{dt}F_Y(t)\,dt\ne1.$

---

**My Difficulties:** For some reason I am not convinced of my work, I think I made a mistake somewhere because the answer seems too easy. Could someone please confirm or deny my worries? Thank you for your time and highly appreciate any feedback.

Comment: Your answer, though easily obtained as you said, is correct!